# How to solve network issue?

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm getting the following error on `npm install`:

> C:\projects\projects>npm install npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall
> open npm ERR! path C:\projects\projects/package.json**strong text**
> npm ERR! errno -4058 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or
> directory, open 'C:\projects\projects\package.json' npm ERR! enoent
> This is related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-12T15_43_40_855Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is no package.json in your directory C:\projects\projects
Should it contain an existing node.js project or do you want to initialize a new project?

If so, use:

```
     npm init
```